# Inversion with adverbials: when do I need the auxiliary?

Tags: subject-verb-inversion

I'd like to know why some inversions need an auxiliary and others don't need one. 
For example: 
"Little did I know about her" auxiliary + subject + verb
Why not "Little knew I about her", which is also an inversion?

But Here comes the sun; Adverb + verb + subject
or down came the rain: Adverb + verb + subject
Why not "Down did the rain come"?

They are all inversions, but some use an auxiliary and some just the verb. 
Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: I guess the short answer is: When you need to invert, and you can't invert the verb, you use an auxiliary.  Did you look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject%E2%80%93verb_inversion_in_English

Comment: Since this is about relatively common inversions (no *specific* issue identified) and any good answer would be useful on ELL, I'm flagging this as off-topic ("belongs on ELL"). Lola, you may not be aware that this EL&U site is for "linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts", whereas your question is probably more suited to our other site [ell.se]. If you have a further question for ELL, be sure to read their guidance on [what you can ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). :-)